# Get additional attributes from group key

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have another problem with LINQ, So what I'm trying to do is create a list of best salesman. My table of `sold_items`, looks like this

```
[ID]
[Name]
[Price]
[Sold_date]
[Salesman_ID]
```

and the table of `Salesmans`

```
[ID]
[Login]
[First_name]
[Surname]
```

I want to sum all the prices, that each individual salesman sold and also have an option to group it by date for example, the best of this month, or this week

```
var query1 = from s in context.Archive
             //join us in context.Users
             //on s.Salesman.ID equals us.ID
             group s by s.Salesman.ID
             into g
             orderby g.Sum(o => o.Price) descending
             select new
             {
                 Salesman_ID = g.Key,
                 Sale = g.Sum(o => o.Price),
             };
```

that works fine, but I only get `salesman_ID`, how to add User `First_name` and `Surname` from `Salesmans` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var query1 = 
    from s in context.Archive
    group s by s.Salesman into g
    orderby g.Sum(o => o.Price) descending
    select new
    {
        Salesman_ID = g.Key.ID,
        Salesman_First_name = g.Key.First_name,
        Salesman_Surname = g.Key.Surname,
        Sale = g.Sum(o => o.Price),
    };
```

And to limit it my a specific date, use something like this:

```
var query1 = 
    from s in context.Archive
    where s.Sold_date >= minDate && s.Sold_date <= maxDate
    group s by s.Salesman into g
    orderby g.Sum(o => o.Price) descending
    select new
    {
        Salesman_ID = g.Key.ID,
        Salesman_First_name = g.Key.First_name,
        Salesman_Surname = g.Key.Surname,
        Sale = g.Sum(o => o.Price),
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the current Line to this.

```
select new { Salesman_ID = g.Key, Salesman_First_Name = g.Key.First_name };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by multiple columns (all the columns you want to retrieve)

```
 var query1 = from s in context.Archive
                         //join us in context.Users
                         //on s.Salesman.ID equals us.ID
                          group s by new    // group by multiple columns
                          {
                            s.Salesman.Id,
                            s.first_name,
                             s.surname,
                          } into g                     
                        orderby g.Sum(o => o.Price) descending
                        select new
                       {
                        Salesman_ID = g.Key,
                        FirstName = g.first_name,
                        Surname = g.surname,
                        Sale = g.Sum(o => o.Price),
                    };
```